# How can I add a bathroom GFCI protected outlet?

Tags: electrical

I have a GFCI outlet in my bathroom (next to a vanity), and want to install a bidet, by the toilet, which will need an outlet. I was advised at the Home Improvement store that since its a bathroom outlet, it needs "a GFCI at the beginning of the run".

Do I need to install a second GFCI in my bathroom? The only reason for the new outlet would be to power the bidet. The existing GFCI is diagonally across (hence inconvenient) so I could use a [Legrand Wiremold](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Legrand-Wiremold-Non-Metallic-PVC-Raceway-5-ft-Wire-Channel-White-10-Pack-NMW1-10/205485209?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&mtc=Shopping-VF-F_D27E-G-D27E-27_2_WIRING_DEVICES-MULTI-NA-Feed-PLA-NA-NA-WIRING_DEVICES&cm_mmc=Shopping-VF-F_D27E-G-D27E-27_2_WIRING_DEVICES-MULTI-NA-Feed-PLA-NA-NA-WIRING_DEVICES-71700000033102358-58700003867202208-92700048704098210&gclid=CjwKCAjww5r8BRB6EiwArcckC7iy7IIFLb_XOfspt02587n1OyxQCVfbeNQtyATO2CDWVcwKHILcnRoCwW0QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

My original plan  was to extend a line from a regular outlet on the bedroom wall, right behind the bathroom, now I realize it was probably unsafe given the steam and moisture in the bathroom.

Answer (score 3):

If you provide power to the bidet, that circuit needs to be GFCI protected.  You can either run a line from the existing GFCI outlet (off the LOAD side, which is protected), or (I think) tap off an existing circuit that may be more convenient and put a GFCI outlet by the bidet.

When I added a washlette to my existing toilet, I chose to do the later as it was easier to tap into an existing circuit up in the attic above the bathroom and drop the cable down through the wall from the attic to near the toilet.

Comment: Bathroom circuits need to be GFCI protected. Additionally, I _believe_ that bathroom circuits need to be _dedicated_. i.e. tapping off of another one in another room is _not_ allowed. I'd wait for the electricians to chime in before following the advice here (or ripping out the wiring and redoing it).

Comment: I'm not sure that all bathroom circuits need to be dedicated.  I know that a bathroom needs to be provided with a dedicated circuit, but that's not the same as saying that every outlet in the bathroom needs to be dedicated.  I agree about waiting for the electricians to comment.

Comment: I'm in agreement there - I'm not implying that a _new_ circuit be run for the 2nd outlet, but that I don't believe it can be tapped off of the _bedroom_ circuit. There should be no issue with running the a new "regular" outlet from the LOAD terminals of the existing GFCI, thus having protection on the new outlet. (Note that a sticker/label should be attached to the new outlet indicating that it _is_ GFCI protected.)

Comment: I read the changes 2020 NEC 210.11(C)(3) to say that the dedicated receptacle circuits are required to feed "countertop and other work similar work surface" outlets. A bidet receptacle could be required to be on a different circuit unless it fits within the single bathroom exception. (This is a change, but it can reflect the intent of earlier code writing panels.)

Comment: Additionally the box store employee was mistaken, the NEC does not require a gfci at the beginning of the run, it says "shall have ground-fault circuit-interrupter protection". This allows breakers, first outlet, or protection at each location. He is likely confusing the AFCI requirements with GFCI requirements.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease Actually, he was likely giving the simplest solution for the average user. Replacing a regular breaker with a GFCI breaker is something many people will never attempt. Protection at each location (or worse, a daisy-chain of GFCI so that multiple trip each time) is what box store employee is trying to advise *against*, to save money & effort - i.e., simplest thing is *often* "GFCI protect the first receptacle in the chain". Incomplete, but largely correct for *typical* situation.

Comment: You must have 1 dedicated circuit and everything in the bathroom can be on this circuit 210.11.c.3 , if you want a circuit for the bidet , one for a heater and one for the receptacles this would be fine. Code states the minimum requirement. All receptacles in a bathroom require GFCI protection.  This dedicated circuit can only feed the bathroom(s). So a second circuit is beyond the requirement and would not be a problem.